# VB.NET DataView RowFilter - multiple conditions - 'NOT LIKE' condition is not filtering

Tags: vb.net, ado.net, dataview

```
dvShipList.RowFilter = "ASNNEED = 'Y' AND ASNFLAG <> 'Y' AND (CUSTOMER_ID NOT LIKE '4570*' OR CUSTOMER_ID <> '1604002' OR CUSTOMER_ID <> '3708001')"
```

The DataView RowFilter is working with the exception of "CUSTOMER_ID NOT LIKE '4570*'".
I have also tried "CUSTOMER_ID NOT LIKE '4570%'" but * and % both work according to MS Docs.

The resulting data is filtered correctly to exclude exact matches for Customer Id's 1604002 and 3708001, but not correct for the NOT LIKE condition.

Does my filter need to be structured different?

Comment: Is there CUSTOMER_ID actually a string type?

Comment: Yes, the CUSTOMER_ID is a string

Comment: I think the ORs are wrong ... as far as I understand you want the IDs to be <> 1604002 AND <> 3708001 AND not like  4570*

Comment: Hmm...good point. Let me tweak it a I will post back